Using Blue Yeti USB mic with Galaxy Tab S8 without headphones?
How do you use the Blue Yeti USB mic with a Samsung Galaxy Tab S8 without plugging in headphones?
If I plug in the mic via a USB-mini to USB-C cable to the tablet, the tablet autodetects it and records with it automatically. The recording quality is a massive upgrade over the awful mic on the tablet.
However, the Blue Yeti's headphone jack tricks Android into thinking that the mic is actually a pair of headphones causing it to try and direct all audio output to the mic as well. Since I'm not using headphones with it (and I can't for my application) I get no sound output while the Blue Yeti is connected.
I figured there should be some sort of option in sound settings to re-enable sound output to built-in speakers, like every other operating system in the world has, but I've looked all through Android's sound settings, but I can find nothing.
Oddly enough, the very first time I plugged in the mic, it worked exactly the way I wanted. When I first used the Voice Recorder app to test, it recorded with the Yeti but still output sound to the tablet speakers. However, after I unplugged the mic and then re-plugged it in, then it began automatically using the mic as speakers.
